# C# LINQ - Зануление внутри массива

Tags: c#, linq

Допустим есть массив: `int[] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,1,4,5,2,2,1}` Мне нужно заменить повторяющиеся числа(если число повторяется больше чем 1 раз) на 0 внутри массива =>`numbers = {0,0,3,0,4,5,0,0,0}` такого формата. С использованием LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ не предназначен для изменения массивов, но раз вам надо одним запросом LINQ, держите. В продакшене так не пишите.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,1,4,5,2,2,1};

numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x =>        
    {
        int ind = 0;
        while(x!= 0 && (ind = Array.IndexOf(numbers, x)) > -1)
            numbers[ind] = 0;
        return x;           
    }).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Вывод

```
0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0
```

**UPD**

для создания нового массива

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,1,4,5,2,2,1};
var newArray = numbers.Select(x=> numbers.Count(z=>z == x) > 1 ? 0 : x ).ToArray();     
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newArray));
```

Вывод

```
0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: А если мне нужно будет записать результат в новый массив/коллекцию ? А не переписывать текущий массив

Comment: @Charlotte то это надо указывать в вопросе сразу

Comment: @Charlotte Обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @Charlotte на здоровье. Выберите ответ, который вам больше помог и поставьте на нем галочку.

Answer (score 1):

Когда мы рассматриваем первый элемент *последовательности* — в вашем примере это 1 — мы не знаем, повторяется он, или нет и не знаем, надо ли заменять него на 0 или не надо.

Поэтому, чтобы решить задачу, нам сначала надо собрать информацию о повторяющихся элементах.

В LINQ есть операция группировки — `group by`, которая позволяет собрать вместе одинаковые элементы.

```cs
var repeats = from number in numbers
              group number by number into piece
              where piece.Count() > 1
              select piece.Key;
```

Немного магии и всё работает. Подробно группах читаем в [документации](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.6.php).

В результате этого запроса у нас будет *последовательность* чисел из массива, которые повторяются. Для вашего примера это будут 1 и 2.

Теперь мы можем пробежаться по массиву второй раз и проверять, встречается очередное число в `repeats` или нет.

Но существует решение в рамках одного *сложного* запроса. Для этого нам надо *соединить* две последовательности — исходную и последовательность повторов. Соединение нужно *внешнее*. Если не знаете, что это, снова рекомендую погрузиться в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins).

```
var results = from number in numbers
              join repeat in (from number in numbers
                              group number by number into piece
                              where piece.Count() > 1
                              select piece.Key)
                             on number equals repeat into results
              from result in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select result == 0 ? number : 0;
```

Последовательность `results.DefaultIfEmpty()` будет содержать почти то, что нам нужно: нули там, где нет повтора и значения там, где повтор есть, то есть числа `{1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1 }`. Чтобы инвертировать последовательность, мы будем брать число `number`, если `result` равен 0, и 0, если не равен. Именно это и делает строка `result == 0 ? number : 0`.

Такие задачки хороши в качестве упражнения, но понимать подобные запросы весьма непросто. Я бы лично в обычной программе в явном виде описал бы, что я делаю, в виде двух отдельных проходов по массиву.

```
var repeats = from number in numbers
              group number by number into piece
              where piece.Count() > 1
              select piece.Key;

var results = from number in numbers
              select repeats.Contains(number) ? 0 : number;
```

Этот код может быть медленным, если количество элементов в `repeats` будет большим. Представим, что у нас миллион `numbers` среди которых сто тысяч `repeats` (повторов). Каждое из миллиона чисел мы будем проверять на равенство со ста тысячами значений. Не быстро.

Решением может являться подходящая структура данных, которая умеет быстро проверять, есть в неё элемент или нет. Хорошо подходит множество на основе хэша — `HashSet<T>`.

Код может быть таким:

```
var repeats = new HashSet<int>(from number in numbers
              group number by number into piece
              where piece.Count() > 1
              select piece.Key);

var results = from number in numbers
              select repeats.Contains(number) ? 0 : number;
```

Comment: Только `from result in results.DefaultIfEmpty()` - `result` нужно заменить например на `r` и далее тоже.

Comment: @Bulson, не обязательно. Я в C# Interactive запрос проверил, прежде, чем опубликовать.

Comment: Почему бы просто не залить в словарь число поаторений каждого элемента, раз уж вы храните повторения в отдельной переменной? Это вроде проще для понимания будет, и группировка не нужна.